# missing library when running make?

Tags: make, mpi

I am trying to install a [program](https://code.google.com/p/mplabs/wiki/QuickInstall) on my machine (running Ubuntu 12.04), but I get the following error when I run `make`:

```
Starting build...
Working Directory : /home/laptop/mplabs_test
Build Type        : 

Generating OMP binary...
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "&" unexpected
make: *** [lbs3d] Error 2
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the error, am I missing a library that I need to install?

Comment: Did you edit `Makefile.in` to "set your compiler and installation directory options"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) issue.

Provided you have the required build environment, it should work if you set `make`'s shell to `bash` explicitly on the command line:

```
make "SHELL=/bin/bash"
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Makefile in `mplabs`:

```
gedit Makefile
```

Search for `|&` and replace all occurences with `|`.